# Keypad scan for microcontroller

Tags: c, driver, microcontroller, keypad

I have developed a c driver for a keypad for a microcontroller. I want to alter it so that when I press a 1, for example, it displays 1 until I press another number. As of now, the number only changes if I press the number meaning it will go away once I release the button on the keypad. Please give me a general idea of how I would go about implementing my desired change.

Comment: Interesting that you managed to develop the keypad scan routine but struggle with this relatively easy change.

Answer (score 2):

Store the last pressed key in a variable that you "display" (or do whatever you want with) until the next key is pressed, when you change the variable to the new key value.

Comment: Is there a general algorithm? As of now, I have a keyUp function that stays in a loop until no key is pressed.

Comment: @user3318660 Can you update some code so that it would be easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

You should create a variable to hold pressed key value, then update your screen when a particular button (key) is clicked. Suppose you have a function named getPressedKey() that returns a numeric value of the pressed key, this is how you would implement a fragment to update screen based on the pressed key.

```
    char pressedKey = 0;
    /*
    *loop endlessly
    *wait for keypress
    *update screen with with pressed key value
    */
    while(1)
    {
    pressedKey = getPressedKey(); //store pressed key in pressedKey variable
    updateDisplay("Pressed key is %c",pressedKey); // display key value
    }
```